# Edge Extension Native Communication and UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, microsoft-edge

I'm providing a new feature in my UWP App through a Edge Extension.
I have written an Edge Extension with the following manifest.json

```
{
"name": "MyExtensionName",
"version": "1.0.0.0",
"description": "MyExtension description",
"author": "Me",
"icons": {
    "16": "icons/logo_16.png",
    "48": "icons/logo_48.png",
    "128": "icons/logo_128.png"
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
        "20": "icons/logo_20.png",
        "40": "icons/logo_40.png"
    },
    "default_title": "MyTitle"
},
"permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "<all_urls>",
    "nativeMessaging",
    "background"
],
"minimum_edge_version": "37.14316.1000.0",
"background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"],
    "persistent": true
},
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "css": ["css/light.css"],
    "js": ["js/content.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
}]
}
```

I can create a connection with this

```
var port = browser.runtime.connectNative("MyAppServiceName");
```

and I have tried to communicate with this

```
port.postMessage({Text: "Hello"});
```

I don't get any error, but I don't get any response from my background task in my UWP App. I don't understand why.

In package.appmanifest of my App, I have added the following code:

```
<uap:VisualElements DisplayName="MyUWPAppName" 
                          AppListEntry="none"
                          Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png" 
                          Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png" 
                          Description="MyUWPApp description" 
                          BackgroundColor="transparent">
```

and in  this

```
<uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
          <uap:Protocol Name="msghost1" />
        </uap:Extension>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.appService" EntryPoint="MyAppService.Class1">
          <uap:AppService Name="MyAppServiceName" />
        </uap:Extension>
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.appExtension">
          <uap3:AppExtension Name="com.test.edge.extension" 
                             Id="EdgeExtension" 
                             PublicFolder="Extension" 
                             DisplayName="ms-resource:DisplayName">
            <uap3:Properties>
              <Capabilities>
                <Capability Name="websiteContent" />
                <Capability Name="websiteInfo" />
                <Capability Name="browserStorage" />
              </Capabilities>
            </uap3:Properties>
          </uap3:AppExtension>
        </uap3:Extension>
```

The AppService is a Runtime Component added as project in the same solution.
Its code is very simple

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.AppService;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;

namespace MyAppService
{
    public sealed class Class1: IBackgroundTask
    {
        private BackgroundTaskDeferral backgroundTaskDeferral;
        private AppServiceConnection appServiceconnection;


        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            this.backgroundTaskDeferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral(); // Get a deferral so that the service isn't terminated.
            taskInstance.Canceled += OnTaskCanceled; // Associate a cancellation handler with the background task.

            // Retrieve the app service connection and set up a listener for incoming app service requests.
            var details = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as AppServiceTriggerDetails;
            appServiceconnection = details.AppServiceConnection;
            appServiceconnection.RequestReceived += OnRequestReceived;
        }

        private async void OnRequestReceived(AppServiceConnection sender, AppServiceRequestReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            // This function is called when the app service receives a request
        }

        private void OnTaskCanceled(IBackgroundTaskInstance sender, BackgroundTaskCancellationReason reason)
        {
            if (this.backgroundTaskDeferral != null)
            {
                // Complete the service deferral.
                this.backgroundTaskDeferral.Complete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to debug the AppService with the option "Do not launch, but debug my code when its starts" and I have noted that I don't get any response (the background task is not invoked).

Somebody know what is wrong (or what is missing)?

Comment: Have you test the official sample on your side ? Can it work well? I want to confirm if you are testing on the correct way firstly.

Comment: I have tryed the sample SecureInput here https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/MicrosoftEdge-Extensions-Demos/tree/master/SecureInput, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have found the solution for my problem:

- in the tag  I must use Name="com.microsoft.edge.extension";
- I have to import the namespace xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities", without adding some capabilities from this;
- The build and deploy must be done for the x64 platform.

With this changes I am able to deploy and get it work the native messaging between my App and the Edge extension.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comment, you even cannot run the official sample successfully on your side, but actually the official sample [`SecureInput`](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/MicrosoftEdge-Extensions-Demos/tree/master/SecureInput) do worked. So that I'm afraid you are not testing the project on the correct way. Please check the following tips if these can help, which are not recommended in the sample:

- Your device has Windows 10 Creators Update or higher, since the native messaging in Edge is supported with Creators Update.
- Ensure the extension developer features is enabled. Type `about:flags` in your edge, and select "Enable extension developer features". Details please reference [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/adding-and-removing-extensions#adding-an-extension).
- Host the test web page. Normally we need a test web page to test this feature, you could  publish the page to IIS and visit it like  `http://localhost/secureinput.html`. Details for how to build a static website on IIS please reference [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/creating-websites/scenario-build-a-static-website-on-iis).
- Debugging the extension scripts firstly to see if the script have any errors. For how to debug please reference [Debugging extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/debugging-extensions).

In your app service, you didn't deal with the received message and you also don't send back message (the `OnRequestReceived`) method is none. You may reference the sample to try to update.

So after deployed, check if the extension is installed correctly and you could try to access the background page of the extension in Edge. And then with the test page ensure you could debug the `content.js` . In that case you may find what's wrong.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your instructions. Now I am able to compile and deploy the official sample. SecureInput works fine. I have tryed to reproduce the code and the configuration in my project, but my project doens't work. The first thing that I noticed is that my edge extension is not installed after the deploy. I think that there are some configuration in my project that it is wrong. I am not able to find that!